# WCF Data Services Metadata Provider and DataServiceKey

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

If I'm unable to annotate my classes with the DataServicesKeyAttribute to make WCF Data Services recognize my property `Id` as a key (since it only recognizes `ID` or `ClassNameID` by default), is there any other option besides writing my own IDataServicesMetadataProvider?

It's pretty stupid on Microsoft's part, considering the default capitalization scheme for the PK when you create an entity in an EDMX model is `Id`, not `ID`....and FURTHER Microsoft's naming convention guidelines suggest using `Id` not `ID` in terms of capitalization. Very stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really can't add the DataServiceKeyAttribute, then yes, the only way is to implement your own provider. Note that if you have an EF provider underneath your WCF Data Service then the key properties will be taken from the EF itself, not from the attributes on the classes. So this probably means that you're trying to do something else than EF. If that's the case, please post more detailed description, maybe there is another way.

Comment: I'm using a custom IQueryable provider with POCO's that are defined in a separate common assembly that I can't add a dependency on System.Data.Services.Client to.

Comment: If that's the case I would suggest going the custom provider route fully. Yes, you will have to "reflect" over the classes yourself, but having the ability construct metadata usually helps a lot with the IQueryable implementation (since you have control over types and such). I think for long-term it's a better (more extensible) approach. And since you're half way there already...